# What Feat or Item do I remember that allows making basic melee attacks at range?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

I stayed up way too late last night reworking a character.  Today I find myself going over some of the things I read.  I just remembered a feat (or something) that gives your melee attacks some range, I want to say Ranged 5) but I can't seem to find it. I looked through quite a few books.  I'm starting to wonder if it was perhaps a dream? It was definitely a 'magically themed' feat, the flavor description said something along the lines of

> you cut the air and wounds appear on a nearby foe

What feat does this?

Character:

- Reworking an Eladrin Mage into an Eladrin Bladesinger, multiclassed
  as a Swordmage.

Books:

- Arcane Power, HotFL, NWN Campaign, HoS?  PH for sure.  Also the AV
  books.

I am convinced this was a feat and not a power.  I looked at a lot of online sources, but quickly moved on if they're aren't from official books.

Currently heroic level (8th), and since I didn't take it (I remember thinking I'd have to get it) I'm guessing it's Paragon or something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have searched the compendium and I think you were looking at the **[Farslayer Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1254)**: (Source: Adventurer's Vault)

> *As you swing this weapon through the air, wounds magically appear on enemies beyond your normal reach.*
>
> […]
>
> **Power (Standard Action):** Make a melee basic attack with this weapon against a target up to 5
>   squares away from you.

Comment: YES!!  thank you so much, I knew I wasn't crazy lol.

Comment: Glad to help, I searched the compendium for:"Wounds appear" and there it was.

Comment: ahhh, didn't realize it had that search power.  Maybe I'll subscribe now haha

Answer (score 3):

**There isn't any feat quite like that, but more limited versions might exist.**

There is definitely no feat that lets you make all your melee attacks as ranged 5 attacks or as melee 5 attacks; that would be seriously overpowered.

I'm wanting to say there's a feat that lets you make a ranged *basic* attack instead of a *melee* basic attack when you make an OA, and possibly feats to let you substitute an RBA for an MBA in other situations. There are 1 or 2 monk daily powers that make your monk melee attacks melee 2 instead of melee 1. There might be feats that change the ranges of a few specific powers (almost always 1-2 at-will powers). The Sigil Carver swordmage paragon path lets you make melee 5 MBAs under certain conditions.

After looking through the books you mentioned (PHB1, AP, HotFL, HoS, NWNCG, PG:FR) I didn't see *any* feats that would let you increase the range of melee attacks under *any* circumstances. The only feats I saw that might even be *mistaken* for doing something like that were the heroic-tier feats in the PHB that increase the range of *ranged* weapon attacks by 5 or the range of *thrown* weapon attacks by 2.

If we look beyond feats, AV2 has the Farbond Spellblade, an enchantment that gives any heavy blade the **heavy thrown 5/10** property. This allows you to use a melee weapon for ranged attacks, but does not turn your melee attacks into ranged attacks.

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, the more I think of how crazy of a feat it would be but... the memory really is quite distinct.  It could have been something like a paragon path power or something I suppose, but I'm still convinced it was a feat - even if it was in a dream lol

Comment: When I get home I'll go through my books, they're all open and it shouldn't take me very long.  If I can't find it then, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @mykepwnage I'll take a look at my books as well when I get home, but that's 9-10 hours away.

Comment: So yeah, as I asked the question, pretty sure you're right and it doesn't exist.  I still feel like I read something *like* it though.  Maybe not a feat.  I know I'll find it again, when I do I'll come back and update lol.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to extend your melee reach to 2 by using a Reach weapon. There are other tricks that can extend your melee reach to 3, 4 or even 5 by Epic but you really need to build for it.

Alternatively you could use a thrown weapon and use ranged basic attacks. With the Intelligent Blademaster feat you could throw Heavy Thrown weapons using you Intelligence modifier but since Intelligence must replace Strength, it will not work for Light Thrown weapons. The extra damage/control that comes from being a Bladesinger, however, is only triggered on a **melee** basic attack. Don't get me wrong, it may be advisable to have a Javelin handy in case you are slowed/immobilized far from the place you want to be as some damage (or a dead minion) is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Blade of the eldritch knight its a magic Weapon that when you use a standard action to make a melee attack with this blade, your melee reach increases to 5 for
that attack, you will find it in adventurers vault 2. maybe thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You may want to take the [Tour] to see how things work here. We seek to have longer, detailed, and complete answers to questions. While this seems to be a good find, I had to go research the item myself to see the actual wording of the effect. You may want to edit your answer to include more detail like that.